# How to set a parent property from within a custom element in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

A few days ago I asked this question [2 way databinding in Aurelia custom elements - bind custom element to parent viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297363/2-way-databinding-in-aurelia-custom-elements-bind-custom-element-to-parent-vie)

Now I need to be able to reuse the `allSelectableValues` from my custom element (my-custom.js) in my parent element (create.js).

I need this for a custom value converter I have on create.js which contains some Ids which I need to display names for instead, by looping through the array of elements, currently fetched and residing in my custom element.

```
**create.html**
<td>${d.SomeID | allSelectableValuesMapping}</td>
```

and

```
**value-converters/all-selectable-values-mapping.js**
export class AllSelectableValuesMappingValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        for(let item in allSelectableValues) {
            if (item.SomeID == value){
                return item.Name;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In the ideal world I'd have hoped something like this would have worked:

```
**my-custom.js**
async attached() {
    this.allSelectableValues= await await this.myService.getAllValues();
    this.parent.allSelectableValues = this.allSelectableValues;
}
```

But my custom element have no idea of the parent which is requiring it.

Does anyone have an idea how to set the parent's allSelectableValues equal to the custom element's allSelectableValues from within the custom element? Or is there another, better way of achieving it, while still maintaining the two-way databound custom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

Please take extra note of the `@customElement('CustomElement')` declarator above the `export class CustomElement` line of code.

### Custom Element View Model

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('CustomElement')
export class CustomElement {
    @bindable arrItems
}
```

### Custom Element HTML

```
<template>
    <div repeat.for="item of arrItems">$(item.someProperty}</div>
</template>
```

### Parent View Model

```
export class ParentViewModel {
    parentArrItems = [];
}
```

### Parent HTML

```
<template>
    <require from="customelement"></require>

    <CustomElement arrItems.bind="parentArrItems"></CustomElement>
</template>
```

Comment: What's with the case sensitive elements names in the DOM?

Comment: Almost: <div repeat.for="item of arrItems">$(item.someProperty}</div>
should be <div repeat.for="item of arr-items">$(item.someProperty}</div> without the camelcasing :-) Thanks!

Comment: I do have one last question. Regarding the value converter in my example above. How do I send over the arrItems (we just got a hold of now) together with the value like in my example? I get arrItems is undefined

Comment: Charleh I can't remember the exact code off the top of my head. It's more of pseudo code. @Dac0d3r I'm no expert but isn't Value Converter more of a temporary front-end transformation of the source data (i.e. it doesn't modify the source data). Can you not apply the value converter to the custom element too or wherever you need it ?