# How to multi-purpose a bindable in a custom element without a view model?

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to use a single bindable in two slightly different ways in a custom element with no view model.

field-input.html:

```
<template bindable="label,type,property">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="${property}">${label}</label>
    <input id="${property}" value.bind="${property}" type="${type}">
  </div>
</template>
```

my-form.html:

```
<form ...>
  <field-input label="Email address" type="text" property="email"></field-input>
```

The **desired** result is:

```
<form ...>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input id="email" value.bind="email" type="text">
  </div>
```

The **actual** result is an error in the console:

```
ERROR [app-router] TypeError: sourceExpression.connect is not a function(…)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `bind` instead of printing the variable inside the quotes:

```
<template bindable="label,type,property,myValue">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for.bind="property">${label}</label>
    <input id.bind="property" placeholder.bind="property" value.bind="myValue" type.bind="type">
  </div>
</template>
```

Every time you want to bind an html attribute, just call `attr.bind="object"`, without the interpolation marks `${}`

**Update from @Seth's solution**

Since you have an input element inside the custom element, it's important to use `myValue.two-way="..."` in the composing view. See [2 way databinding in Aurelia custom elements - bind custom element to parent viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297363/2-way-databinding-in-aurelia-custom-elements-bind-custom-element-to-parent-vie)

Comment: When I do that it binds to the value of *property*, which is "email". That means the value of the input is always "email" instead of the value of viewmodel.email.

Comment: bind the `property` object to the placeholder attribute, like this `placeholder.bind="property"`. Then, create another bindable property called `myValue`, bind this to the value object. Like this `value.bind="myValue"` Then, in the parent object, bind the `viewmodel.email` to `myValue`. See my updated answer

Comment: I suspected that's what I would have to do. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: And since I have an input element inside the custom element, it's important to use `myValue.two-way="..."` in the composing view. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297363/2-way-databinding-in-aurelia-custom-elements-bind-custom-element-to-parent-vie.